# Returning Count of Users from Multiple Table With Same Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables 1 is User table and 2 in Engage table

in User table I have UserID and other fields and in Engage table I've EntityType and UserID field, EntityType can be "Login" or any other what I want is I want result in one row which should returns count of totalusers, count of totalusers who have EntityType "Login" exists in Engage table and totaluser who have engage which any other EntityType other than "Login"

every member who's engage with anything have already entry of Login

What I tried is :

```
SELECT COUNT(U.UserID) as TotalUser, COUNT(E.UserID) as ActiveUser, COUNT(EU.UserID) as EngagedUser
FROM (`Users` U)
LEFT JOIN `Engagement` E ON `E`.`UserID`=`U`.`UserID`
LEFT JOIN `Engagement` EU ON `E`.`UserID`=`EU`.`UserID`
WHERE EU.EntityType!="Login" AND E.EntityType="Login"
```

But this query is returning too many rows

Comment: You can use a `procedure`.

Comment: please let me know how it works ? a basic thing, rest I'll take care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use subselects for each user count you want to get - something like:

```
select (select count(*) from Users) as TotalUser, 
(select count(*) from Users join Engagement on Users.UserId=Engagement.UserId where EntityType='Login') as ActiveUser,
(select count(*) from Users join Engagement on Users.UserId=Engagement.UserId where EntityType!='Login') as EngagedUser
```

When one user can have more records in Engagement table:

```
select (select count(*) from Users) as TotalUser, 
(select count(DISTINCT Users.UserId) from Users,Engagement where Users.UserId=Engagement.UserId and EntityType='Login') as ActiveUser,
(select count(DISTINCT Users.UserId) from Users join Engagement on Users.UserId=Engagement.UserId where EntityType!='Login') as EngagedUser
```

Comment: Right answer. Should give what OP has asked

Comment: almost works but just one issue totalusers are less than 50 which is correct, activeusers is 28 which is also correct but engage users are 700+ which is not correct

Comment: If one user can have more rows in Engagement table than it will not work correctly I guess.

Comment: I found probably better solution with COUNT(DISTINCT)